# Send file size and then the file itself

Tags: c, sockets, recv

> client-side code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h>  
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void error(char * msg){

    perror(msg);
    exit(0);

}

// Returns an string array from function
char *buff(const char *path){
    int end = 0;
    unsigned char * buf;
    int f_write = open(path,O_RDONLY);
    end = lseek(f_write,0,SEEK_END);
    lseek(f_write,0,SEEK_SET); 
    buf =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(end+1));
    read(f_write,buf,end);
    close(f_write);
    buf[end+1]= '\0'; 
    return buf;

}
     //connects to the socket
int connection(int portno,struct hostent * server,int sockfd){
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int conn =0;
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family= AF_INET;
    bcopy((char*)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    conn = connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
    return conn;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sockfd = -1;
    int check =0;
    char projname[100]= "project1";
    int portno = -1;
    int conn = -1;
    int file_size =0;
    ssize_t len;
    int n = -1;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[256];
    int fd =0;
    if(argc < 3){
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n",argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    // getting the portnumber
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        error("Error opening socket");

    }   
    // getting the hostname
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if(server == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    conn = connection(portno,server,sockfd);
    if(conn < 0){

        printf("%s\n",strerror(errno)); 

    }
    int path = open("text.txt",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    if(path < 0){
        printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
    }
    int remain_data = file_size;
    printf("Printing out the file size ");
    printf("%d\n",file_size);
    char *buffer1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*file_size+1);
    len = recv(sockfd,buffer1,BUFSIZ,0);
    printf("%d",len);
    buffer1[file_size]= '\0';
    printf("printing the sentence\n");
    printf("%s\n",buffer1);

    int total_read_bytes =0;
    int nread =0;

     return 0; 
}
```

> server-side code

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

void error(char * msg){

    perror(msg);
    exit(1);

}

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int sockfd =-1;
    int newsockfd = -1;
    int portno = -1;
    int clilen = -1;
    int remain_data =0;
    char buffer[300];
    char buffer1[300];
    int peer_socket = -1;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
    int n = -1;
    struct stat file_stat;
    char file_size[256];
    ssize_t  len;
    int sent_bytes =0;
    int path = open("project1/text.txt",O_RDONLY);
    read(path,buffer1,30);
    buffer1[31]= '\0';
    printf("%s\n",buffer1);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sockfd <0){
            error("Error opening socket");
    }

    bzero((char*) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

    portno=atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
            error("Error on Binding");

    }

    listen(sockfd,5);
    int fd = open("project1/text.txt",O_RDONLY);
    fstat(fd,&file_stat);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    peer_socket = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);

    sprintf(file_size,"%d",file_stat.st_size);
    //sends file size
    len = send(peer_socket,file_size,sizeof(file_size),0);

    if(peer_socket <0){

            error("Error on accept");       

    }

    off_t offset = 0;
    remain_data = file_stat.st_size;
    //send the file
    while(((sent_bytes=sendfile(peer_socket,fd,&offset,remain_data))>0) &&( remain_data>0)){
            fprintf(stdout,"1.Server sent %d bytes from files data, offset is now : %d and remaining data = %d\n",sent_bytes, offset,remain_data);
            remain_data -=sent_bytes;
            fprintf(stdout, "2. Server sent %d bytes from files data, offest is not: %d and remaing data = %d\n",sent_bytes, offset,remain_data);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to get the size of my file from server side but I am unable to get file content from my server on client side. My client prints out an empty space where the data of the file is supposed to be, I don't know if I am using the `recv` function correctly the file correctly.
P.S I understand that I must close the sockets when finished.

Comment: SideNote: You are accessing out of bound here     `buffer1[file_size+1]= '\0';`

Comment: still does not work if I make it buffer1[file_size] = '\0';

Comment: Can you create [mcve] ?

Comment: lseek returns `off_t` not an int.

Comment: so when I get the return value from len it returns 0 which means the socket closed, how do I prevent the socket from closing?

Comment: You never read the file size.

Comment: OT: regarding: `void error(char * msg){

    perror(msg);
    exit(0);`  a return value of 0 is typically an indication of success.  Suggest replacing: `exit(0)` with `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the posted code for the server, when run through the gcc compiler, outputs a long long string of warnings, many of which are serious.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding; `serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);`  the function: `htons()` is expecting a parameter that is a `short unsigned int`, not an `int`

Comment: Running the client code through the compiler results in a long long list of warnings, many of which are serious.  Note my prior comment about enabling the warnings when compiling

Comment: regarding: `bzero((char *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));`  The first parameter is expected to be a `void*`, not a `char*`  Please read/understand the MAN pages for the C library functions that you use.  Similar considerations exist for several other C library functions that are called in the posted code, like `bcopy()`

Comment: OT: regarding: ` buf =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(end+1));`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  2)  The returned type, in c, is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: OT: regarding: ` read(f_write,buf,end);`  1) variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)`  The parameter `f_write` is very misleading.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int f_write = open(path,O_RDONLY);` Always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful (>=0)

Comment: regarding: `buf =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(end+1));`  This is expected to allocate enough room for the contents of the file (you might want to look into `mmap()`) However, it is actually allocating a char pointer for each byte in the input file.  I.E. (depending on the underlying hardware architecture) 4 or 8 times as much memory as needed

Comment: regarding: `buf[end+1]= '\0';`  this is NOT (necessarily) where the data ends.  Suggest using the returned value from the call to `read()`  Also note the in C, an array index has the valid range 0...(number of elements in array -1) so the offset `end+1` is not correct

Comment: regarding: `int remain_data = file_size;` and all following references to `file_size`.   That variable is set to 0, strongly suggest obtaining the actual file size and using that instead of 0

Comment: regarding: ` len = recv(sockfd,buffer1,BUFSIZ,0);`  Isn't `BUFSIZ` defined as 4096?   but the input buffer, pointed to by `buffer1` has a length of 0,  So executing that `recv()` function results in a buffer overflow and undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `buffer1[file_size]= '\0';`  Since the pointer `buffer1` points to a allocated memory size of 0, this is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: There are LOTS of other problems in the posted code, but the above comments should get you started in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

For safety and robustness, you must check the return values of *all* the standard library functions you call to check for errors.  For `recv()` and `read()`, however, you must check and appropriately handle return values *for correctness*.  These functions do not guarantee to transfer the full number of bytes requested, and for network connections it is reasonably common that they don't.  If you want to fully transfer a specific number of bytes then you must be prepared to use multiple `recv()` or `read()` calls to do so, generally by calling the function in a loop.

You do not check the return value of your `recv()` call, so if you have a short read -- or if there is an error or if the remote side closes the connection without sending anything -- then your client will not notice, and will simply output whatever garbage happens to be in the buffer.

Comment: @ryyker, I have not provided a code example, but I *have* explained what needs to be done: use a loop to perform potentially multiple `recv()` calls to achieve a transfer of the full number of bytes.  There are already *many* examples of this on SO and elsewhere around the Net.